# How can i set the heap size in GraphDB? (Standalone Server)

Tags: memory, jvm, sparql, graphdb

I want to configure the heap memory size but it's not clear for me, from the documentation.
It says:

*You can control the heap size by supplying an explicit value to the startup script such as graphdb -Xms10g -Xmx10g or setting one of the following environment variables:*

*GDB_HEAP_SIZE - environment variable to set both the minimum and the maximum heap size (recommended)*

*GDB_MIN_MEM - environment variable to set only the minimum heap size*

*GDB_MAX_MEM - environment variable to set only the maximum heap size.*

Any clearer steps?

Comment: what is not clear with the documentation? Depending on your operating system, just look how to set an environment variable and then set it as documented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case if you want to increase the Xmx you need to start GraphDB with ./graphdb -Xmx10g. The other way is to use "set GDB_HEAP_SIZE=10g" in the terminal, but I recommend passing the parameter as in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this with sh and most other shells:

```
GDB_HEAP_SIZE=10g ./graphdb
```